# SSIS split column to multi column

Tags: ssis

i have column which contain data like :

Value 1\Value 2

Value 1\ Value 2\ Value 3

i don't know how many each rows have "\" and I need to split this data using SSIS Derived Column.
Could you help me?

Comment: Perhaps look at the script component instead...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're going to run into is that eventually you must define an upper limit to the number of columns, at least if you're going to use a `Data Flow Task` It does not support dynamic columns.

A script task or component will help you in the splitting of data. The String library has a Split method that takes user specified delimiters